# Laravel Nova depends on function does not work properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want to display a Boolean depending on another value, but I do not receive any data in the callback function.

```
            
            BelongsTo::make('Vertrags transaktion ID', 'insurance', 'App\Nova\InsurancesFromCompany'),

            Boolean::make('Zusatzversicherung', 'additional_skiteacher_insurance')
                ->hide()
                ->dependsOn(['insurance'],
                    function ( $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
                        Log::debug($formData->insurance);
                    }),
```

Normally I should be able to receive the insurance Id in the log but the entry is empty

```
[2022-05-12 16:30:10] local.DEBUG:
```

Comment: Maybe because of the ->hide()? if you replace $formData->insurance in your LOG by a string, does it come by the log and logs actually something?

Comment: and where do you want to show the boolean? Only on index and detail? or also on create and update?

Comment: I fixed the issue, i was able to get the id with ```$request->viaResourceId```

Comment: I'm getting JavaScript error trying to show / hide a Nova field with `dependsOn` - did you get it working?